# $\det(x)\,t-1$ is irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Why is $\det(x)t-1$ an irreducible polynomial in $K[x,t]$ where $x$ is a matrix? I know that $\det(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Do you mean the linear polynomial $\det(x)t-1$ in the polynomial ring $A[t]$, where $t$ is a variable and $A=K[x]$for some fixed matrix $x$?

Comment: If $\det(x)t-1=p(x,t)q(x,t)$, then either $p$ or $q$ must have degree $1$ and the other degree $0$ on $t$. Assume $q(x,t)=q(x)$ has degree $0$ on $t$. Then $\det(x)t-1=p(x,t)q(x)$. Putting $t=0$ we get $-1=p(x,0)q(x)$. Therefore, $q$ is invertible.